# Enumerating ConcurrentDictionary after adding and removing entries causes high CPU

Tags: c#, .net

My program had a problem wherein it would continue to use more CPU than usual after handling a massive amount of data. I traced the problem back to a piece of code that enumerates over a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

I knew this would cause high CPU usage when enumerating the dictionary while it held millions of entries, however I raised an eyebrow when the CPU usage didn't drop back down to it's original level after the dictionary had emptied. It seems like the dictionary was doing a lot more work behind the scenes after the mass add-then-remove, but why? When enumerating the dictionary before anything is added to it, CPU usage stays firmly at 0%.

Why is this happening? Is there anything I can do to prevent it from happening?

Here's a code snippet that reproduces the problem:

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

const int count = 3000000; // High CPU.
//const int count = 100; // No issues.

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    dict.TryAdd(i.ToString(), null); // Add lots of entries.
}
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    object nullObj;
    dict.TryRemove(i.ToString(), out nullObj); // Then remove them all.
}

GC.Collect();
Debug.Assert(dict.IsEmpty);

Console.WriteLine("Enumerating");
while (true)
{
    // Enumerate the dictionary. Takes up lots of CPU despite being empty,
    // but only if lots of entries were added then removed.
    foreach (var kvp in dict) { /* Empty. */ }

    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: Even if it looks like the dictionary is empty for you, the ConcurrentDictionary doesn't know that another thread hasn't changed that situation. What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: I'm trying your sample code now in a .NET 4.5 console project and does not get the high cpu usage at all. It holds steady on 8-9%. That is expected since you're doing a loop that actually does something. Even if your `dict` is empty, you're calling `dict.GetEnumerator()` and `Thread.Sleep` with only a few milliseconds to sleep. What version of .NET are you using?